Issues adding two heightmaps to gazebo
I'm trying to have two different image based heightmaps within gazebo at the same time, as far as I'm aware, it's possible, but I'm starting to think it might not be. I can spawn each heightmap in a world on there own and there's no issues, whenever I try to put them both in the same world one doesn't appear. It's listed under the models list and if I use the spawn model command it says its successful, but nothing appears in the world and there is no error or even a mention of it trying to spawn it I the log files. If I have a plane as part of the heightmap, the plane will spawn but the heightmap won't. I've made sure the models won't collide, made sure they've got different variable names, checked permissions and variable names, but no matter what I can't seem to do it.
Any help is very much appreciated, if it can't be done is there a way to set multiple frictions on one heightmap, that's why I'm trying to spawn in two.
